# "Column Index" on a server-side processed DataTable

Tags: php, jquery, indexing, datatables, server-side

Does anyone know how to add a ***column index*** to a **server-side** processed [**DataTable**](http://www.datatables.net)? Basically like http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/counter_columns.html, but this example builds the index by client, which is not supported by using the common server-side version.

The author Allan gave three hints, but actually I don't get it:

- *Modify the data at the server (the ideal solution)*
- *Modify the data as it comes back from the server*
- *Edit the draw callback function to take into account the page start position.*

I stumble and stumble - and I don't know how to start and how to do it. Maybe YOU could help me out? That would be awesome!

Comment: Which version of dataTables and which server sided code are you using?

Comment: @mainguy Thx for your reply! The newest version v1.10.0 and for the server-sided code the example (examples/server_side/scripts/server_processing.php), which is included in the download package. Maybe you could also take a look at here (http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/60427/#Comment_60427) where the author Allan gave a new hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am referring to the simple.html example here.

In server_processing.php replace the last lines with:

```
    /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
     * If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP
     * server-side, there is no need to edit below this line.
     */
    require 'ssp.class.php';
    $result=SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns );
    $start=$_REQUEST['start'];
    $idx=0;
    foreach($result['data'] as &$res){
        $res[0]=(string)$start;
        $start++;
        $idx++;
    }
    echo json_encode($result);
```

This will generate an row-id to the array that is returned. Also you need to shift the number in the $colums array by 1 since the id is inserted at position 0.

```
$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'first_name', 'dt' => 1 ),
    array( 'db' => 'last_name',  'dt' => 2 ),
    array( 'db' => 'position',   'dt' => 3 ),
    etc ...
```

Finally you need to add an additional id column to your html:

```
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
            etc ...
```

That is what Allan meant with "*Modify the data as it comes back from the server*". And this has some drawbacks. When using server sided processing sorting, filtering and searching happens in the genrated sql query that fetches the data from your db. Since you don't seem to have an incremental id field in you db: **No sorting the ID for you, come back one year!**

This brings us to Allans suggestion Nr.1 "*Modify the data at the server (the ideal solution)*" which basically means: Give your db an incrementing id and use it as a simple field. This can be done with a simple update query. Of course if you don't want to sort after row id this answer will do.

Comment: Really really helpful, @mainguy! Thank you very much for that. I only changed to `$start=$_REQUEST['start']+1;` to start with 1, not with 0.

Comment: $start=$_REQUEST['start']; $start++; Glad it helped you!

Comment: Btw. You don't really need $idx. That was just a leftover i forgot to remove.

Comment: There is a major problem with this solution: when changing the page, the numbers still start from 1.
So if I display 10 results per page (1-10) the next page should start from 11. But it doesnt. It still starts from 1 to 10..
Is there something that I missed ? I found the answer! you have to add the start parameter when you call server_processing.php like this: server_processing.php?start=0 Thank you for the whole solution! Very good.